Rubber plant new growth deformed
Rubber plant seems to have some problem, not sure what it is. When it gets new growth, the growth looks stunted and deformed. I tried to take pictures and hopefully, you can see from the pictures the new growth looks very strange. Plant has been repotted in new soil and has partial shade upstairs.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Their specific problem is that whenever their rubber plants "gets new growth, the growth looks stunted and deformed."  There are additional details on the plant's potting history and sunlight exposure.  And pictures!  Please clarify your specific problem with this question or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're complaining about.
